# VS Code Open code in browser

Tags: vs-code

My VS Code project is already authorised with Salesforce sandbox and I am able to deploy or retrieve the files successfully.

How can I launch the Salesforce org from the currently opened apex class or aura comp or any other metadata.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Primarily I just want to double check that my current project is pointing to the right Salesforce instance as I doubt that the code is not getting refresh even I just run the retrieve command recently and this is a common requirement to open your current apex class(or any other metadata) in browser.

Comment: @sunilgupta are you looking to open the instance in a browser or open the component that is currently open in VS Code in the browser?

Comment: How are you retrieving the apex class? You can check your default org set in the vs code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a SFDX Command to open the current org that VS Code is working against:

> > SFDX: Open Default Org

[image]

Additionally, on the bottom left of the status bar the currently connected org alias is shown and clicking the icon besides it opens the org.

[image]

Under the hood both the "Open Default Org" and status strip button do the same thing. They issue the SFDX command:

```
> sfdx force:org:open
```

If you wanted to drive that directly into a particular location you could extend that with the `-p`/`--path` command line option. However, that would require knowing the correct landing URL for the metadata type currently being viewed. Not many metadata types have a direct view URL format.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, that's what I was looking for, on top of that I have one more question -
While working with a static resource (an individual HTML file) in VS Code, I found that html file is not retrieving the latest code from the org even the retrieve command showing successfully, is that a limitation with VS Code when you work on static resources.

Comment: @sunilgupta I'd recommend asking a new question for that specific problem. That way you will get more direct answers. The comment sections aren't great for longer discussions outside of the original question.